# How many Views are possible in a view flipper in android?

Tags: android, viewflipper

I am developing an application in android in which i want to show about 170 images, but i want user can view images by finger either right or left . After searching from internet i got a solution, therefore i had use View flipper in my application It will work when the counting of images are 15, when the counting increasing above fifteen it will crash.
Can you tell me the reason for this or is there a limitation in view flipper that we cannot show more than 15 views.

Give me any suggession for solve my problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to use [`Gallery`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) ([Gallery tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html)), ViewFlipper will load complete view in memory, so when you load more images it will take more memory and there is good chance for `OutOfMemoryError`.
For displaying Images Gallery is the best choice

Comment: Can you give me any other option rather than gallary.

Answer (score 1):

The view flipper has not such limitations. Probably the issue is that you're loading in memory all those images. Try to avoid to have more than 2 or 3 images in memory at any given time or you'll run out of RAM

Comment: as i new to android i can't understand what you said i can show you my code

Comment: can you give  me any solution for it.

Comment: Use the Gallery as suggested in another answer