# Why cant my view flipper show more than 3 views?

Tags: java, android, slideshow, viewflipper

I am trying to make a slideshow app for a school project, and I have it working when the view flipper contains 3 images. However, when I add a 4th layout and another picture the program crashes.

Any idea why? Thanks!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
    private ViewFlipper myViewFlipper;
    private AnimationListener mAnimationListener;
    private Context mContext;

    MediaPlayer soundOne, soundTwo, soundThree;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private final GestureDetector detector = new GestureDetector(new SwipeGestureDetector());

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mContext = this;
        myViewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) this.findViewById(R.id.view_flipper);
        myViewFlipper.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent event) {
                detector.onTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
            }
        });


        findViewById(R.id.play).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //sets auto flipping

                myViewFlipper.setAutoStart(true);
                myViewFlipper.setFlipInterval(4000);
                myViewFlipper.startFlipping();
                soundOne = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.one );
                soundTwo = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.two );
                soundThree = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.three );

                //generate random number
                Random randomGenerator = new Random();
                int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(3) + 1;

                //picking the right sound to play
                switch (randomInt){
                    case 1: soundOne.start();
                        break;
                    case 2: soundTwo.start();
                        break;
                    case 3: soundThree.start();
                        break;
                }



            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.stop).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //stop auto flipping
                myViewFlipper.stopFlipping();
                soundOne.stop();
                soundTwo.stop();
                soundThree.stop();

            }
        });


        //animation listener
        mAnimationListener = new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                //animation started event
            }

            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }

            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                //TODO animation stopped event
            }
        };
    }


    class SwipeGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            try {
                // right to left swipe
                if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    myViewFlipper.setInAnimation(loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.abc_fade_in));
                    myViewFlipper.setOutAnimation(loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.abc_fade_out));

                    // controlling animation
                    myViewFlipper.getInAnimation().setAnimationListener(mAnimationListener);
                    myViewFlipper.showNext();
                    return true;
                } else

                if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    myViewFlipper.setInAnimation(loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.abc_slide_in_top));
                    myViewFlipper.setOutAnimation(loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.abc_slide_out_bottom));

                    // controlling animation
                    myViewFlipper.getInAnimation().setAnimationListener(mAnimationListener);
                    myViewFlipper.showPrevious();
                    return true;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know why but when I've looked at the logcat it's referring to the layout file 'activity_main'. I've look at it and can't see why it's not working as previously I had 3 relative layouts and changed it to 4.

here is logcat

```
03-06 17:29:08.973  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-06 17:29:08.973  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
03-06 17:29:08.973  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
03-06 17:29:08.973  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
03-06 17:29:09.583  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 87K, 10% free 17905K/19779K, paused 60ms, total 60ms
03-06 17:29:09.653  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 38.204MB for 12544016-byte allocation
03-06 17:29:09.673  32420-32424/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 6% free 30153K/32071K, paused 8ms+2ms, total 25ms
03-06 17:29:09.793  32420-32424/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 6890K, 23% free 30155K/38983K, paused 12ms+3ms, total 30ms
03-06 17:29:09.903  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 23% free 30155K/38983K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
03-06 17:29:09.963  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 50.166MB for 12544016-byte allocation
03-06 17:29:10.003  32420-32424/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 18% free 42405K/51271K, paused 11ms+3ms, total 32ms
03-06 17:29:10.093  32420-32424/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 6890K, 18% free 42407K/51271K, paused 2ms+5ms, total 41ms
03-06 17:29:10.163  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 18% free 42407K/51271K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
03-06 17:29:10.243  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 62.131MB for 12544016-byte allocation
03-06 17:29:10.313  32420-32424/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 15% free 54657K/63559K, paused 12ms+6ms, total 66ms
03-06 17:29:10.573  32420-32424/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 6890K, 15% free 54659K/63559K, paused 12ms+4ms, total 46ms
03-06 17:29:10.653  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 15% free 54659K/63559K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
03-06 17:29:10.653  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 12544016-byte allocation
03-06 17:29:10.673  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 8K, 15% free 54650K/63559K, paused 25ms, total 25ms
03-06 17:29:10.673  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide E/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Out of memory on a 12544016-byte allocation.
03-06 17:29:10.673  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
03-06 17:29:10.673  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40c585e0 self=0x400c70d8
03-06 17:29:10.673  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ | sysTid=32420 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1075144752
03-06 17:29:10.673  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=64 stm=33 core=1
03-06 17:29:10.673  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
03-06 17:29:10.693  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:500)
03-06 17:29:10.693  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:353)
03-06 17:29:10.713  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
03-06 17:29:10.713  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1935)
03-06 17:29:10.713  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
03-06 17:29:10.723  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:120)
03-06 17:29:10.723  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:110)
03-06 17:29:10.723  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
03-06 17:29:10.743  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
03-06 17:29:10.783  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
03-06 17:29:10.813  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
03-06 17:29:10.813  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
03-06 17:29:10.813  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
03-06 17:29:10.813  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
03-06 17:29:10.813  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
03-06 17:29:10.813  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
03-06 17:29:10.813  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
03-06 17:29:10.813  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
03-06 17:29:10.813  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
03-06 17:29:10.813  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
03-06 17:29:10.813  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
03-06 17:29:10.813  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:262)
03-06 17:29:10.813  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
03-06 17:29:10.813  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ at firstapp.imageslide.imageslide.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
03-06 17:29:10.813  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
03-06 17:29:10.813  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
03-06 17:29:10.813  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2035)
03-06 17:29:10.813  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2096)
03-06 17:29:10.813  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
03-06 17:29:10.813  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
03-06 17:29:10.813  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-06 17:29:10.843  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
03-06 17:29:10.843  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
03-06 17:29:10.843  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-06 17:29:10.843  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-06 17:29:10.843  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
03-06 17:29:10.843  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
03-06 17:29:10.843  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-06 17:29:10.843  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/dalvikvm﹕ [ 03-06 17:29:10.843 32420:32420 D/skia     ]
    --- bitmap->allocPixels failed
03-06 17:29:10.893  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
03-06 17:29:10.893  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c57378)
03-06 17:29:10.893  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{firstapp.imageslide.imageslide/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #74: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2071)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2096)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #74: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:262)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
            at firstapp.imageslide.imageslide.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2035)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2096)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:262)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
            at firstapp.imageslide.imageslide.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2035)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2096)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:500)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:353)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1935)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
            at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:120)
            at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:110)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:262)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
            at firstapp.imageslide.imageslide.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2035)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2096)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-06 17:29:13.893  32420-32420/firstapp.imageslide.imageslide I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 32420 SIG: 9
```

Comment: See this- http://stackoverflow.com/a/6280695/713778

Comment: Post your code and a stack trace of the error that's happening.

Comment: i added the code to the orginal comment thanks!

Comment: `the program won't run` perfect description. I need to get a patent for that phrase. Would make me rich and improve the quality of questions here. As you are new here: "won't run" is not good enough. If it crashes, post the LogCat with the stack trace. If you don't know what that is, google it! Also check [FAQ] for details and helpful information on how to ask here

Comment: Thereis the logcat aswell, sorry I should have said it crashed.

Comment: From the log it looks like you are hitting a memory limit due to the image size.  It's failing on a memory allocation close to 12MB.